# Is there any difference in meaning between "ask something from someone" and "ask something of someone"?

Tags: prepositions

Can you please tell me if there is any difference in meaning between *ask something from someone* and *ask something of someone*? For example:

> We always need to ask that kind of information **from** a customer.
>
> We always need to ask that kind of information **of** a customer.

Are both perfectly natural in the sentence? Are there contexts where you would use one but not the other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use '*ask something of someone*'. But we cannot use 'ask something from someone'.

ask something of someone (to request someone to give us something)- Can I ask a favour **of** you? (=Can I ask you a favour?)

She asks too much **of** me.

ask someone something- Can I ask you a favour? (= Can I ask a favour **of** you?)

We also use 'ask for' when we request someone to give us something.

She asked me **for** money.

Answer (score 2):

Technically, your second example is the correct one:

> We always need to ask that kind of information of a customer.

However, you probably won't hear that in American English because it's very formal. You're more likely to hear:

> We always need to **ask for** that kind of information from a customer.

But the best choice is probably:

> We always need to **get** that kind of information from a customer.

Answer (score 0):

Neither of your sentences make sense.

To *[ "ask" + something + "of" + someone ]* means to ask someone to *do something significant* for you.

> Could you make dinner for me? I hope it's not too much to ask of you.

There's no structure to "ask" something "from" someone.